# Show that $\| \phi_x \| = \| x \|_\infty$, where $\phi_x(y) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} x_n y_n$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $\mathbb{F} \in \{\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}\}$. By definition, we have that:

$$\ell_1(\mathbb{Z}) = \{(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \subseteq \mathbb{F}: \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} |x_n| < + \infty\}, \quad \ell_\infty(\mathbb{Z}) = \{(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \subseteq \mathbb{F}: \sup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \{|x_n|\} < + \infty\}$$

Fix $x \in \ell_\infty(\mathbb{Z})$ and define $\phi_x: \ell_1(\mathbb{Z}) \to \mathbb{F}$ given by
$$\phi_x(y) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} x_n y_n$$

I want to show that $\| \phi_x \| = \| x \|_\infty$, where $\| \phi_x \| : = \sup_{y \in \ell_1(\mathbb{Z})}\{|\phi_x(y)|: \| y \|_1 \le 1\}$ (I already proved $\phi_x$ is linear).

Let $y \in \ell_1(\mathbb{Z})$ such that $\| y \|_1 \le 1$. Thus,
$$\phi_x(y) \le \|x\|_{\infty} \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} |y_n| \le \|x\|_{\infty} \Longrightarrow \| \phi_x \| = \sup_{\| y \|_1 \le 1} \{|\phi_x(y)|\} \le \|x\|_{\infty}$$

Then, it is required to show, that it exists $y \in \ell_1(\mathbb{Z})$ such that $\| y \|_1 \le 1$ and $\|x\|_{\infty} \le | \phi_x(y)|$. If $x \equiv 0$, $\|x\|_{\infty} = 0$ and we are done. Suppose then, that $x \not \equiv 0$, then $\|x\|_{\infty} > 0$.

I cannot find that $y \in \ell_1(\mathbb{Z})$ such that $\| y \|_1 := \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} |y_n| \le 1$ and $\|x\|_{\infty} \le |\phi_x(y)| = \Big| \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} x_n y_n \Big|$.

Any hints or help is really appreciated!! My poor intuition suggests that $y$ must satisfy that $\| y \|_1 = 1$ and use the $\|x\|_{\infty}$ on it's definition.

Comment: Fix $n$ such that $x_n\neq 0$ and let $$y=(0,0,\ldots, 0, \overline{x_n}/|x_n|,0,\ldots),$$ where the non-zero term is in the $n^{th}$ spot.

Comment: Thanks! For this fixed $n$, it necessarily happens that $|x_n| = \| x \|_\infty$? Other ways I don't clearly see why $\| x \|_\infty \le \frac{|x_n|^2}{|x_n|} = |x_n|$?

Comment: Not necessarily for this fixed $n$, but you can do this for any $n$ such that $x_n\neq 0$, get an inequality for each $n$, and take a supremum.

Comment: Got it, very simple reasoning. Thank you very much!!

Comment: We should note that the existence of $y$ such that $\|x\|_{\infty} \le | \phi_x(y)|$ is _not_ necessary.

Comment: You're welcome. Another quick, somewhat-related observation: If $X,Y$ are Banach spaces and $T:X\to Y$ is a linear operator, and if $x=\sum_{i=1}^n w_ix_i$ is a convex combination of $x_1,\ldots, x_n$ (by which we mean that the $w_i$ are positive and sum to $1$, then by the triangle inequality, $$\|Tx\|\leqslant \sum_{i=1}^n w_i\|Tx_i\|\leqslant \sum_{i=1}^n w_i \max_j \|Tx_j\|=\max_j \|Tx_j\|.$$  

From this together with the fact that the convex hull of $\{\pm e_n:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is dense in the unit ball of $\ell_1$, for any $T:\ell_1\to Y$, $$\|T\|=\sup_n \|Te_n\|.$$

Comment: @BrianMoehring Why is it? Does it hold directly?

Comment: Consider $x_n=1-2^{-n}.$ Then $\|x\|_\infty>|\varphi_x(y)|$ for any $y$ with $ \|y\|_1=1.$

Comment: The supremum, as in the example given by Ryszard, may not be attained by any $y$ such that $\|y\|_1\leq 1$.  What you need to show is the existence of a $y_\varepsilon$ for any $\varepsilon >0$ such that $\|x\|_\infty-\varepsilon \leq |\phi_x(y_\varepsilon)|$.

Comment: If $\sum_n |y_n|=1$, then $$|\sum_n x_ny_n|\leqslant \sum_n |x_n| |y_n|,$$ which we can think about as a weighted average of the $|x_n$ terms with weights $|y_n|$. Each term $|x_n|$ satisfies $\|x\|_\infty$. Then the weighted average can equal the upper bound $\|x\|_\infty$ if and only if $|x_n|=\|x\|_\infty$ for every term with positive weight (that is, for each $n$ such that $|y_n|>0$). Ryszqrd's example does not have any $n$ for which $|x_n|=\|x\|_\infty$.

Comment: @user469053 That's pretty much strong and interesting! I have never worked before with convex hulls and my topological skills are not really shaped. I understand that the lastly result is taking the $\sup$ because the previous result holds for finite convex combinations and that the $\sup$ is being taken in function of every canonical vector of the basis of $\ell_1$, because of the density of the convex hull. The thing that is still confusing is why $T: \ell_1 \to Y$. It smells like some categorical morphism for me here..

Comment: Using this idea, you can show that there exists $y$ with $\|y\|=1$ and $|\phi_x(y)|=\|x\|_\infty$ if and only if the supremum $\sup_n |x_n|$ is a maximum.

Comment: It's generally true that if $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and convex and $U=\overline{\text{conv}}(K)$, then $\sup_{x\in U}f(x)=\sup_{x\in K}f(x)$. this comes up in finite dimensional spaces, where the unit ball is always the closed, convex hull of its extreme points (and $\pm e_n$ are the extreme points of finite dimensional $\ell_1^N$ spaces). For infinite dimensions, we don't necessarily have that anymore (the unit ball of $c_0$ has no extreme points).

Comment: This also comes up in other contexts, such as the simplex method in linear programming. The simplex method tries to optimize a convex objective function on a convex set by moving from one extreme point to the next in a way that always improves the objective. 

The fact that $B_{\ell_1(\Gamma)}$ for any non-empty set $\Gamma$ is the closed, convex hull of $\pm e_\gamma$, $\gamma\in \Gamma$, seems related to (though not in a way I can put my finger on at the moment) the fact that $\ell_1(\Gamma)$ are projective in the category ${\bf Ban}$.

Comment: @user469053 That's why it is required to use $\ell_1$ when $X$ has infinite dimensions.

Comment: @BrianMoehring It was not clear moments before, but now it is. Thanks! The necessity so use an $\epsilon$ comes from the fact that it is required a collection $(y_n) \subseteq \ell_1(\mathbb{Z})$ to operate with limits (or equivalently with supremums).